# UWP - I can't edit a field on the Application class from the UI thread

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, ui-thread, storagefile

I have a property `Files` of type `ObservableCollection<Element>` in my `Application` class.

```cs
public sealed partial class App : Application
{
    public string CurrentPath;

    public ObservableCollection<Element> Files;

    public async void RefreshFilesAsync()
    {
        Files.Clear();

        var folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(CurrentPath);
        var foldersRequest = folder.GetFoldersAsync();
        var filesRequest = folder.GetFilesAsync();

        var folders = await foldersRequest;
        var files = await filesRequest;

        foreach (StorageFolder directory in folders)
        {
            Files.Add(new FolderElement(directory));
        }

        foreach (StorageFile file in files)
        {
            Files.Add(new FileElement(file));
        }
    }

    // ...

}
```

`Element` is a wrapper class of mine for `StorageFile` objects. This class is made so that setting a new value to the Name property calls the API to rename the actual file.

```cs
public class Element
{
    public string Name
    {
        get => StorageFile.Name;
        set =>
        {
            StorageFolder.RenameAsync(value, NameCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName).Completed = (IAsyncAction act, AsyncStatus status) =>
            {
                (App.Current as App).RefreshFilesAsync();
            };
        }
    }

    public StorageFile StorageFile { get; }

    //...

}
```

I have a `DataGrid` linked to the Application property `Files`, so you can deduce that whenever I rename the column for the file name, the API is called to perform the real renaming.

Here's when my problem occur. The API call succeeds and the file is renamed, but inside `RefreshFilesAsync()`, when `Files.Clear();` is called, I get an exception `The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread`.

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: You're calling an async void method from inside the lamba. That's throwing it back on the thread pool.  Make that method that you call from the App a regular method.  Or at least use the dispatcher to get back to the window thread for the Files.Clear

Comment: I don't see that you're using the dispatcher anywhere now.

Comment: Yep, sorry for that, I messed up with wrong files, I was using the dispatcher in another file which looks a lot like this one. I fixed the initial post and added the solution for future readers. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run code with the UI thread, I used `Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync()`, and put it in a separate async method. The exception does not appear anymore.

```cs
public string Name
{
    get => StorageFolder.Name;
    set => RenameAsync(value);
}

private async void RenameAsync(string newName)
{
    await StorageFolder.RenameAsync(newName, NameCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
    await Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => (App.Current as App).RefreshFilesAsync());
}
```